# WIFI not connecting Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: 22.04, 23.04, 23.10

I am new to Ubuntu and running Ubuntu 23.10 "Mantic Minotaur" on my pc (stand-alone).
From past couple of days, my computer is not being able to connect to a particular wifi (Main wifi of out house) but is being able to connect to other networks like hotspot from my mobile phone.

Detailed issue:-

1. When trying to connect, it shows
   CONNECTION FAILED:-

activation of network connection failed.

Attempts at trying to solve it.

1. Turned on metered connection [Didn't work]
2. Disabled IPv4 and IPv6 alternatively [Didn't work]
3. used `ifconfig up [name of network]` [Didn't work]
4. used `nmcli connection up [name of network]` [Didn't work]
5. Reinstalled `linux-headers` by using `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)` and sudo reboot [Didn't work]
6. reattached wifi adapter to all ports of the pc case [Didn't work]
7. used dhclient [Didn't work]
8. Installed net-tools [Didn't work]

I have tried many methods of solving this issue but all of them are in vain.
Therefore I request you to look into my issue and give your solution for this recurring problem